# Tkinter - My button wont call the command and it shows no error

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a back button on my canvas in `tkinter`, I am hoping it will either bring it back to a different canvas, or it will call the command.

It is not calling the command I put and it is not showing an error.

This is the function:

```py
def instructions():
    print ("TEST")
    #root4.destroy()
    root5 = Tk()#creates pop up box
    game2 = Canvas(root5, width = 800, height = 600, bg = "slate gray")
    game2.pack()

    welcomeText2 = game2.create_text(150, 50, text = ("Welcome Back!"), font = ('Calibri', '16'))
    instructions2 = game2.create_text(175, 115, text = "Instructions:", font = ('Calibri', '14'))
    Instructions2 = game2.create_text(190, 325, text = "To play the game Who Did It?\n all you need to do is read the\n details of the story and think\n about who you think did the\n crime. There will be 3 options\n and when you have your guess\n select the person you think did\n it. Once you hit confirm the answer\n will be displayed! Hit the back\n button at any time to read the\n instructions again, or choose a\n new story. However, all progress\n will be lost if you hit the button.\n To start the game select the story\n and hit continue on the left!", font = ('Calibri', '10'))

    rectangle2 = game2.create_rectangle(30, 140, 350, 510, width = 2)

    detective2 = PhotoImage(file = "detective.gif")
    Detective2 = game2.create_image(600, 100, image = detective2)

    storyChoiceText2 = game2.create_text(550, 250, text = "Please Select Story", font = ('Calibri', '14'))

    storyChoice2 = StringVar(root5)
    storyChoice2.set("Select")
    option_menu2 = OptionMenu(root5, storyChoice2, "Story 1 - Easy", "Story 2 - Medium", "Story 3 - Hard")
    option_menu2.pack()
    storyChoiceWindow2 = game2.create_window(550, 300, window = option_menu2)

    continueButton2 = Button (root5, text = "Continue", command = choice)
    coninuteGameButton2 = game2.create_window (700, 550, window = continueButton2)
```

and this is the button code:

```py
backButton = Button(root2, text = "Back", command = instructions)
backButtonGame = Story1.create_window(750, 550, window = backButton)
```

Any solutions?

Comment: You don't want to create a brand new window here, just just want to reset the controls that are on your window.  You can add a separate `restore_instructions` function that resets all of the text boxes, or at least you could if you had stored the controls in a structure that you could access from outside.  This is why GUI applications are almost always class based -- so you can maintain state information.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a complete [mcve]

Comment: `root5`? The rest of the code scares me. And in a more serious note, `Tk()` should definitely not appear more than once in your program. Tkinter has `TopLevel` for that.

Comment: Does it mean that you do not see the "TEST" in the console when you click the `Back` button?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a button-function for your button and define its properties outside that specific function, but on another note this code is hiatus and should not be written with more that one root, try using TopLevel instead and then seperately define your button again.